# ASP.NET Core how to init connection string in first run-time?

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string

I am building an enterprise application and i want for the first time the use run the website to be able to choose the SQL server to connect to, and the Database in that server. after that the application always run on that configurations like normal asp.net core app do.

I know that connection string is stored in `appsettings.json` so i was thinking about changing it's value at run-time after choosing this configuration, but after searching a lot i think this is not possible.

What do suggest is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need to change config value at run-time?

Comment: I want the user to choose the config and in the next run the config loaded as usual

Comment: I want to run a page for the user to choose Sever address and Database after that save it in the config and run the actual website

Comment: Here this approach called as Code-first method..First you have to create connection strings in `appsettings.json`.Then create `ApplicationDbContext ` and finally configure it with SQL Server configuration in `Startup.cs ` file.
Follow the steps given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `reloadOnChange` to true when you are adding `appsettings.json` to `ConfigurationBuilder`:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

then create a class for connection string

```
public class ConnectionString
{
    public string Default {get; set;}
}
```

And in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.Configure<ConnectionString>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
}
```

Now this configuration is available through dependency injection.

```
public class HomeController : Controller  
{
    private readonly ConnectionString _connectionString;

    public HomeController(IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionString> connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString.Value;
    }
}
```

`IOptionsSnapshot` can reload configuration data when it changes.

More info about [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration).

Answer (score 0):

You must to load the appsettings.json file in Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false) 
      .Build();

    string conStr = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    // your code


    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: How i will run the application without connecting to DB and after choosing config i want to save it in config

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed following NuGet Packages before connect to the SQL Server Db.

[image: Requested NuGet Packages]

First you have to create connection strings in `appsettings.json` like below

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-O57GSNN\\MSSQLSERVERNEW,Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"},
```

> Here, DefaultConnection is connection Name you are going to use.Please provide any meaningful name you want and it will be use when configuring.Also provide Server Name from SQL Server Management Studio(see the picture below) and Provide a name for your database (Will be created).

[image: Connect to SQL Server]

Then create `ApplicationDbContext.cs`  file and type below code

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
            
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
}
```

> Book is the Model in my App.

Finally configure it with SQL Server configuration inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`  file.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
```

> DefaultConnection is connection Name which was already mentioned in `appsettings.json`